# Getting BackbaseConfigurationException while serverstartup (Webshpere 8.5.5)

Tags: websphere, backbase-portal, backbase

However the config file for which it complains is at the correct location I checked 10 times.

Please help

```
[26-2-17 15:27:38:716 CET] 00000045 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [BA621 PBI Portal Manager#portalserver.war]:.Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Portal Foundation Spring MVC'
[26-2-17 15:27:38:718 CET] 00000045 SystemOut     O 15:27:38.718 Portal Foundation [server.startup : 1] --  ERROR c.b.p.f.p.r.PortalDispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationDao' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/data/apps/BA621%20PBI%20Portal%20Manager.ear/portalserver.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.backbase.portal.foundation-configuration-5.6.3.0.jar!/com/backbase/portal/foundation/integration/configuration/impl/ConfigurationDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.backbase.portal.commons.configuration.exceptions.BackbaseConfigurationException: No configuration file could be found at location: c:datawasbsbconfigeditorialdeviceConfig.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) ~[spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) ~[spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1704) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:411) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: com.backbase.portal.commons.configuration.exceptions.BackbaseConfigurationException: No configuration file could be found at location: c:datawasbsbconfigeditorialdeviceConfig.xml
    at com.backbase.portal.foundation.integration.configuration.impl.ConfigurationDaoImpl.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationDaoImpl.java:139) ~[com.backbase.portal.foundation-configuration-5.6.3.0.jar:5.6.3.0-2016-12-09 22:03]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: it seems like backbase is looking for a config file at the location c:datawasbsbconfigeditorialdeviceConfig.xml which is evidently not the case...

Comment: Yes as looking at the error it seems the same but unfortunately the file is located at the said location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem is because of the path of config file. Try to use forward slash '/' instead of '\' and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. Thanks for your answer however this was solved days ago